# When saving image for Web, outlines change

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, images, png, image-quality

I have an imagemap with a click and mouseover function on several areas.
I edited and saved the images in Photoshop with the option "Save for web". I used PNG-8 with 256 Colors.
Performing the mouseover, the image changes. All the outlines of the forest etc. seem to be moving when I move the mouse over the mapped areas. Also the headline changes (a lot actually)
A partly working example is here http://fonag.org.ec/inicio/material-didadico.html
Hover over the "hidden" highlighted stuff behind the trees on the very right side (cyan and green).

Any ideas why that is and even better, suggestions how to avoid this? Since I have an imageflip, I want to overlay the images exactly without any movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at the images from the site, it seems that they were not saved exactly the same.

Displayed image:

[image]

Hidden image:

[image]

The bottom image seems a bit grainy compared to the top image. I would double check to make sure both images were saved the same, and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: I cannot see your images but that did the trick. I had to save the "baseline" image again... Forgot about that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help!